# Using findstr to pass to a variable

Tags: regex, batch-file, filenames, batch-processing, findstr

I've got some files I'm running with a batch file that loops through everyone in a directory and dumps certain data into a sql table. I'm adding in a time stamp that I'm passing into a variable and trying to add to the sql table using sqlcmd the only problem is that to add in all relevant columns for that entry, I need to pass the names of the files that are being added to the sql table.

Okay here's the catch... the names being added to the sql table aren't the actual file names but database names that can be found in each of these xml files (close enough to xml). So I know where that is and every single one looks something like this abcdir (rest of the name) where the abcdir is a string that starts every single database.

So I thought I could use the findstr function to get the database name but I have very little experience with regex and I'd like to be able to parse out the  tags and be left with just name=abcdir (rest of the name)

** * I didn't think any of my code would really be necessary since I'm just asking questions about a particular command but if thats not the case then let me know and I'll post it* **

**EDIT:** Okay so each file will have something like this if opened in notepad.

```
<Name>ABCDir Sample Name</Name>
```

or

```
<Name>ABCDir Sample Name2</Name>
```

and I'd like ABCDir Sample Name to be passed to a batch variable. So I thought to use findstr.
I have very little grasp of regex but I've tried using `findstr >ABCDir[A-Za-z] \path\filename.ext`

Comment: `findstr` is helpful to find lines containing strings, but it won't return *only* the match.  It always returns the entire line.  You may need to parse the line with a `for /f "delims=<>"` or something.  Easiest solution would be instead to use [gnuwin32 grep](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm) and `grep -Eio 'name=[^"]+'` or similar.  But yeah, I think it'd be helpful if you could post some example close-enough XML, as well as the code you have tried to scrape it that isn't successful.

Comment: I've added an edit. One issue I've had with findstr is that I don't have one word files and it seems that if I put in findstr \path\This is my file name.ext 

It will return `FINDSTR: Cannot open path    FINDSTR: Cannot open This     FINDSTR: Cannot open is` and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented above, `findstr` (or `find`) will let you scrape lines containing `<Name>` from a text file, and `for /f "delims=<>"` will let you split those lines into substrings.  With `findstr /n`, you're looking for `"tokens=3 delims=<>"` to get the string between `<Name>` and `</Name>`.

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "file=temp.txt"

for /f "tokens=3 delims=<>" %%I in ('findstr /n /i "<Name>" "%file%"') do (
    @echo %%I
)
```

I'm using `/n` with `findstr` to insert line numbers.  The numbers aren't needed, but the switch ensures there's always a token before `<Name>`.  Therefore, the string you want is always `tokens=3` regardless of whether the line is indented or not.  Otherwise, your string could be token 3 if indented, or token 2 if not.  This is easier than trying to determine whether the tags are indented or not.

Comment: This looks brilliant but I'm confused. I'm assuming `find` is what you're using to search for the relevant test but how is it searching for the correct information?

Comment: `findstr` displays only lines from `%file%` that contain `<Name>`.  The `for /f` loop does stuff with each line output by `findstr`.

Comment: Can you explain a few parts of this? The `"%file=temp.txt%"`, `"<Name>"` and `"%file%"`? Is name and %file% just place holders?

Comment: Syntax of `findstr` is `findstr /switches "Search string" "file-to-search"`.  Do `findstr /?` from a console window for more information.  They aren't placeholders.  It is literally searching for a less-than, an N, an a, etc. in whatever text file is defined by `set "file=filename.ext"` above.  Please salt to taste.  If what you want to match isn't `<Name>` but is `ABCdir`, then `findstr /n /i "ABCdir" "%file%"`.  It is a literal search, not a regexp search.  You can do a regexp search if you wish, though.  Again, see `findstr /?` for more information.

Comment: So then wouldn't it need to be `('findstr /n /i "<Name>ABCDir" "%file%"')`?

Comment: If your close-enough XML files contain more than one `<Name>` line and you need to be more specific in your search, then sure.